# Add unescaped entities to document with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have a document that looks like this:

```
<text>foo
    &lt;bar&gt;
    baz
</text>
```

That is, containing text nodes with line breaks, entities and the like.

Due to one of the databases and search engines we use (not my choice) I have to append `&xA;` to each line within that text node. Here's what I tried.

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML("<text>foo\n&lt;bar&gt;\nbaz</text>")
text_node = doc.xpath("/text")[0]
old_content = text_node.content.to_s
new_content = String.new
old.content.each do |line|
    new_content << line.sub(/$/, "&xA;")
end
text_node.content = new_content
text_node.to_xml
```

Unfortunately, that escapes the entities themselves and I get:

```
"<text>foo&amp;xA;\n&lt;bar&gt;&amp;xA;\nbaz</text>"
```

I am looking for a way to preserve existing entities but add new literal entities within the text content. Also worth mentioning this system is running older libraries (ruby 1.8.7, nokogiri 1.5.0).

Edit: This is not a duplicate of the question on using the XML builder. I tried using the builder and my problems multiplied: it doesn't insert `&xA;` (or `&#10;`) but instead a newline. This is a problem because the system I'm storing in removes newlines from data. It also escapes my existing entities so I end up with things like `&amp;gt;`

Comment: I am not using the XML Builder, although I can give that a shot instead.